# Outdated scripts and UI in ExtJS application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Just faced a very strange behavior of my ExtJS application. Sometimes I can see old JavaScript code or outdated ExtJS views. Even if I reload webpage with Ctrl+F5 I can found old content. Sometimes I can see correct page, but then reload it an find out it's outdated.

And seems like there can be mixed content. For example, I remove some label and then add some forms. And sometimes I can see both forms and label.

Clearing browser's cache doesn't take any effect as well as opening page on clear VM.

I tried to put

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        disableCaching: false
    });
    Ext.data.Connection.disableCaching = false;
    Ext.data.proxy.Server.prototype.noCache = false;
    Ext.Ajax.disableCaching = false;
```

into `launch` function of my `Ext.application` instance before creating main view, but it doesn't seem like there's any effect.

This is very weird because I have never seen this in my application before.

**UPD:** right now I can see outdated panel, but code in js is ok (the difference is that there's no one of the labels in new version). This is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers are more aggressive than others when it comes to caching 'static' resources. 
Typically they use URL patterns to cache.

If you are including scripts yourself you can append a date parameter to the script resource url kinda like this: `src='/js/myfile.js?date=1234567'` where you dynamically generate a new time stamp every time the page loads (either server side or through JS)

ExtJS automatically adds `_dc=timestamp` param to the file resources it loades through loader and any AJAX requests it makes.

Comment: Added timestamp to js - didn't help. Also, those old scripts appear even in fresh new browsers, so I think this is ExtJS caching problem.

Comment: wait how are those 'old' scripts being referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it: I accidentally defined object with same xtype and got some kind of race condition. And in spite of JS itself was ok, sometimes I saw the panel from another JS.